# Using Java to get OfficeLibre Cell value

Tags: java, libreoffice-calc

I can not seem to find any documentation on accessing a value in a .ods table, specifically OfficeLibre from Java. I am using OfficeLibre as a background program for a JavaFX program to dump and get data to, and I can not figure out how to access Cell A1, for example, which holds "Entrees".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations of libraries that can work with .ods files, or have you already chosen something, for example the UNO API?  The first type of question is considered off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Apache odf toolkit-Simple Api, [here](https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/index.html) which is an easier to use version of Apache's ODFDOM Api.

Comment: The link has moved to [https://odftoolkit.org/simple/index.html](https://odftoolkit.org/simple/index.html). Beware: the Simple API has been deprecated in the 0.9 release of the ODF Toolkit and removed in 0.10.